# Is there a way to change space size between chars in a string?

Tags: python, string

let's say I have this string:

```
my_string='hello'
```

Is there a way to change the spacing between each charcter in the original string?
What I mean in spacing is like:

```
new_string='h e l l o'
```

I want to create customzied space,not space like this:('one space' key)

```
' '
```

Basically,change 'one space' to my own defintion of 'one space',not necessary using space key.(What I  mean in not necessary using space key is not using it like that:(three 'one space' key))

```
'   '
```

Comment: `" ".join(my_string)`?

Comment: Or, for longer spaces, `"   ".join(my_string)`. You're not changing the definition of anything, you're just using multiple spaces. If I buy two apples at the grocery store, I haven't changed the definition of "apple", I just happen to have multiple of them in my hand.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I think you didn't anderstand exactly what I meant.What I meant is how can I create new symbol of space using python that isn't composed of spaces.For example,supposing regular space is 2px,then I want to create 1.5px space (or 1.1px,1.2px...etc)

Comment: @OlvinRoght look at my comment towards 'SilvioMayolo'

Comment: If you *really* want to, you could allocate one of Unicode's [private use characters](https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) for your space character. This would involve creating your own font, setting it as the font in your terminal, distributing it with your application, and requesting that Python use that font. Also making sure that whatever terminal you're in can handle variable-width characters, as many have trouble with it. It would require a firm understand of Unicode and character encodings, but it *can* be done. Question is: Why would you want to?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I want to use it for placing text in separated columns with some library for pdf(PyMuPDF if it's relevant for answering) with specific font,but the 'space' which used in the font isn't satisfying me in any way,so I wanted to change the space/whitespace to fit better.

Comment: Use a tab character instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = "Hello"
print(" ".join(my_string))
```

Comment: look at my comment towards 'SilvioMayolo'

Answer (score 0):

to get it a bit more flexible according the number of spaces, we can use this:

```
my_string='hello'
count = 1
print((" " * count).join(my_string))
```

Comment: @Iroth look at my comment towards 'SilvioMayolo'

Comment: @michael what you can not do is to say that a space has to have a defined measure for you. in a console environment (including fonts) all letters have the same width. what you can try is to use special whitespace characters from the unicode character set. have a look here:  https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html